# Pass parameter to .sql file from Batch file (MariaDB)

Tags: mariadb

I have a situation where I want to pass 1 parameter while calling the sql file from .bat file. Based on that parameter I want to perform below action:

```
If (Passed parameter) = 1 then
use <abc>';
else
use <xyz>;
end if;
```

Explored the option where this can be done using -e parameter, but not able to do that successfully. Can someone help me in resolving this problem?

Pseudo code:

```
If (Schema Flag) = 1 then
use <abc>';
else
use <xyz>;
end if;
```

Comment: Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: `.bat` files for doing anything non-trivial become too clumsy.  Change to a real programming language.